# Code formatting tool with netbeans integration and continuous integration

Tags: c, netbeans, continuous-integration, coding-style, mplab

I am working with MPLAB X which for those who don't know an IDE based on Netbeans. We are also using Git with continuous integration. I have now started to work in several different tests for our projects.

For example, MPLAB lets you choose which encoding you want to use in your projects and UTF-8 is not the default option so from time to time we would find problems opening the projects in different platforms. Now I test that every source code file is properly encoded.

We would also like to check code formatting and style. From what I've seen Netbeans comes with a tool to format code for you, but I don't see how to run this tool to print formatting mistakes as a test in our server. I have also seen that there are many tools like uncrustify that should be able to run in our server but they are not integrated with our IDE.

I would prefer not to maintain two different configuration files for this task, for this reason I am asking if anybody knows if there is a tool that can be run both in a Linux based server and that can be integrated with Netbeans for this task.